# Arduino Timer Works strangely

Tags: c, arduino

I'm making an Arduino Hour / Minute / Second Timer but there is a problem

```
void loop() {

    lcd.setCursor(0,1);

    delay(1000);
    sec++;

    if (sec == 60){
        sec = 0;
        minute ++;
    }

    if(minute==60){
        minute=0;
        hour++;
    }

    lcd.print(hour);
    lcd.print(" : ");
    lcd.print(minute);
    lcd.print(" : ");
    lcd.print(sec);
    lcd.print("");  
}
```

Error Video :
https://youtu.be/2cMLli3gHRQ

Until 60 Seconds it works correctly but after 60sec
it turns to 19, 29, 39 ...
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to print an extra space or leading zero to the display.

What happens is that you have `59` and then print `1` which replaces the `5` but leaves the `9`:

```
58
59
..
19
29
..
```

To fix this, either write 1_ (where _ is a space), or 01 (or _1) to the display.

---

Edit: here's a quick fix for your newly posted code:

```
if (hour < 10) {
    lcd.print(" ");
}
lcd.print(hour);
lcd.print(" : ");
if (minute < 10) {
    lcd.print(" ");
}
lcd.print(minute);
lcd.print(" : ");
if (sec < 10) {
    lcd.print(" ");
}
lcd.print(sec);
lcd.print("");
```

Alternatively you could first format a buffer using `sprintf()`, and then send that buffer to the LCD.

Comment: Thanks to comment but still I don't know how to fix the code

Comment: @JungBrownWhite Please show the code where you write to the display (or where you prepare the string).

Comment: Thanks I added "_" after (sec) so it fixed

Comment: @JungBrownWhite Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem :)